# Why does using mongoose .save() function throws me an error?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

This function is throwing an error where product.save() is not a function and i cant figure out why. Maybe there is an error where i call increaseStock and mabye thats whats making the function fail?

```
const increaseStock = async (productId, quantity, price, creator) => {
  try {
    const product = await Product.find({ name: productId, creator: creator });
    if (!product) {
      const error = new Error('Could not find any product');
      error.statusCode = 404;
      throw error;
    }
    const newStock = parseInt(product.stock) + Number(quantity);
    product.stock = newStock;
    product.price = price;
    product.finalPrice =
      price + (Number(product.percentage) * Number(product.price)) / 100;
    await product.save();
  } catch (err) {
    if (!err.statusCode) {
      err.statusCode = 500;
    }
    console.log(err);
  }
```

The other function where this function is called is:

```
exports.addPurchase = async (req, res, next) => {
  const errors = validationResult(req);
  if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
    const error = new Error('Validation failed, entered data is incorrect');
    error.statusCode = 422;
    throw error;
  }
  try {
    const purchase = new Purchase({
      description: req.body.description,
      ticketType: req.body.ticketType,
      ticketSerie: req.body.ticketSerie,
      ticketNumber: req.body.ticketNumber,
      total: req.body.total,
      details: req.body.details,
      creator: req.groupId,
      supplier: req.body.supplier
    });
    let details = req.body.details;
    await details.map(async detail => {
      await increaseStock(detail.product, Number(detail.quantity), Number(detail.price), req.groupId);
    });
    await purchase.save();
    res.status(200).json({
      message: 'Purchase created.',
      purchase: purchase
    });
  } catch (err) {
    if (!err.statusCode) {
      err.statusCode = 500;
    }
    next(err);
  }
};
```

Answer (score 2):

`await Product.find(...` return an array of documents so there's no method `save()` on `product`. Look like what you need is [findOne()](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/model.html#model_Model.findOne) method. Something like:

```
const product = await Product.findOne({ name: productId, creator: creator });
```

Comment: Thank you so much that worked, i didnt realize I was using .find instead of .findOne.